# Adding a div with 5 contents after every div with 6 contents in a foreach loop

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

So basically what I need to output is this..

[image]
[image]

I currently have this code. I'm very confused on how to proceed on this one.

```
  <?php
    $terms = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22];
  ?>

  <div class="container text-center">
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <div class="row">
      <?php
        foreach($terms as $term) : ?>
        <?php if ($count == 6) :  ?>
     </div> 
      <div class="row">
      <?php $count = 1; endif; ?>

      <div class="col-sm-2">
      <?php echo $term; ?>
      </div>
      <?php $count++; endforeach; ?>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

Comment: Oh boy, this is so messed up!

Comment: I know and I'm sorry. I just can't sleep thinking about this.

Comment: Have you tried the css solution I shared below? Might help your sleep issue haha

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried but should work out if you have that $table array... Hope it helps...

```
$table = [ 
     0 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     1 => [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5],
     2 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     3 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
]

 <div class="container text-center">
       <?php 
        foreach($table as $div) {
           echo '<div class="row">';
           foreach($div as $number) {
                if(count($div) == 5) {
                 $add_offset = " col-md-offset-1 ";
                }
                echo '<div class="col-md-2 '.$add_offset.'"';
                echo $number;
                echo '</div>';
           }
           echo '</div>';
        }
       ?>
 </div>
```

EDIT: Again, haven't tried it but you might have an idea of how it should work, maybe adapt a little bit if you get some errors or not exactly what you wanted. Worth the shot.

```
<?php
$terms = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22];   
$count = 0;
$ct = 0;

echo '<div class="container text-center">';
while($count != floor(count($terms)%6)) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
        $repeat = 6;
        if($count % 2 == 1) {
            $add_class = "col-md-offset-1";
            $repeat = 5;
        }
        while($ct != $repeat) {
            echo '<div class="col-sm-2 '.$add_class.' ">'.$ct.'</div>';
            $add_class = '';
            $ct++;
        }

    echo '</div>';
    $count++;
}
echo '</div>':
```

Comment: Thank you, Praem. But I don't have the table array. I'm fetching it dynamically.

Comment: You're complicating your life having a $terms = [1,2,3,4,5,6, 7 ...]
Maybe we can help you fetching that array, would be a lot easier than making a complicated script that will be hard to maintain in the future ....
But well, it's your choice, we can make something work but that won't be a clean code

Comment: I'm fetching it from a database so I don't really have much control in that array.

Comment: Well that isn't a problem, once you get the data from your database you're free to set up your array, you don't necessarily need to use the default fetch. Anyway, I've edited my post trying to use your original array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to select patterns of child elements. In this example, every 7th & 11th item are given unique margin properties that interact with other child elements. No need for PHP loops.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 46px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.item:nth-of-type(11n+0){
  margin-right: 24px;
}
.item:nth-of-type(11n-4){
  margin-left: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```